# How to fix these issues in CSS in navigation menu?

Tags: html, css, navigation, sites

Please help me to fix these issues in CSS (without JS). I am studying and can't find answers to some problems with navigation. Please don't blame me :)

I created navigation and first screen for the site but stumbled with these questions. Here is a screenshot with all things: https://prnt.sc/ln3ytx and my pen on Codepen: `https://codepen.io/a007mr/pen/mQKyYM`

1. How to make background hover for all line? 
   My code is `.menu-item ul a:hover {color: #000000; background: #d2d4d6;`
   but it doesn't work as well. How to make it like this: https://prnt.sc/ln3mvm
2. When I open the drop-down menu, part of navigation is jumping to the right. How to avoid this jump?
3. How to make navigation button in the corner for any desktop size? I am using 
   `margin: 15px;` 
   but it doesn't work well when I will make more screen resolution. It is not responsive. The button will not be in the right corner if I choose the larger desktop.
4. The same issue with all navigation. How to make a position for navigation 
   in one place for any desktop size?
5. How to open dropdown through click (not hover) and hide drop-down menu only through click? My code `li:hover > ul`. If I change on `li:active > ul` then drop-down menu appears only when I hold the button. How to make like *click button -> we show drop-down menu and can choose something -> *other click on "Learn more" and menu is hidden.
6. How to make margin for  below the main button? :)
   I wrote `margin-top: 20px;` but it doesn't work.
7. How to make the background of all navigation without margin?

What's wrong? How can I fix it? Please, help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a SINGLE specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score -1):

I will be try give you some reply:

> How to make background hover for all line? My code is .menu-item ul a:hover {color: #000000; background: #d2d4d6; but it doesn't work as well. How to make it like this: https://prnt.sc/ln3mvm

```
1) Try uses block elements. Remember that css property 
 display: block; makes your element a block element.
```

> When I open the drop-down menu, part of navigation is jumping to the right. How to avoid this jump?

```
2) Your items in the list must be made as blocks and it item (li>a) need to be 
increased.
```

**Common example:**
   `https://codepen.io/bear-wolf/pen/YRvoWO?editors=1100#0`